# Attached db version

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, version, sql-server-2012

We have a database that was created in SQL server 2005. The db's were detached from 2005 and attached to SQL server 2012. The db's were not upgraded to the new format.
Now my question is, is there a query I can run that tells me that the attached db's are still in 2005 format? A version number or something that would indicate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select name, compatibility_level
from master.sys.databases
```

80  = SQL Server 2000;
90  = SQL Server 2005;
100 = SQL Server 2008;
110 = SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Thank you very much. exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

To tell the version of the database use:

```
SELECT @@VERSION
```

And here is a comprehensive article on [How to determine the version and edition of SQL Server and its components](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185). It also has mapping between version numbers and product names.